# deploying Reactjs project with json-server on gh-pages

Tags: reactjs, deployment, render, github-pages, json-server

i'm trying to deploy Reactjs project with json-server , first i deployed json-server data on render.com but when i deployed the reactjs on github pages or vercel , it doesn't work
so how can i deploy react project
i'm trying to deploy the project on github pages and vercel but not working
[here is my package.json and data.js files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4fHd.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HXyc.png)

Comment: if  you face any problem after going through my answer do comment

Answer (score 0):

its not possible to host json serve on github as it dont provide any servers...but i can help you with hosting it for free ..just follow these steps

step 1 -just go to https://replit.com/ and sign up there... after signup you will have your dashboard there create a new repel and when it asks for template just choose the "NODE JS" option [image: like this] .

step 2- now just paste the below code in your index.js file.

DONT FORGET TO CHANGE YOUR FILE NAME AT LINE 3 from db.json to your file name.

```
const jsonServer = require('json-server');
const server = jsonServer.create();
const router = jsonServer.router('db.json');
const middlewares = jsonServer.defaults();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

server.use(middlewares);
server.use(router);

server.listen(port);
```

Step 3 - now there you will see a package .json file replace its code with the following code.

```
{
  "name": "jsonserver",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "��#\u0000 \u0000j\u0000s\u0000o\u0000n\u0000s\u0000e\u0000r\u0000v\u0000e\u0000r\u0000\r\u0000 \u0000",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/geekyvinayak/jsonserver.git"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/geekyvinayak/jsonserver/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/geekyvinayak",
  "dependencies": {
    "json-server": "^0.17.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.20"
  }
}
```

Step 4- now upload you json file. from upload file options present at left menu. BUt make sure that index.json line 3 code and your file number match.
[image]

step 5: Now just run the code from button at center top of website and in output box it will show outbut with url using which you can access the json file.

[image]

note-
NOW YOU CAN MAKE GET POST PUSH DELETE AND OTHER OPERATIONS OF JSON SERVER ON THAT LINK YOU GOT ON OUTPUT WINDOW BUT MAKE SURE YOU COPY THE LINK FROM THERE AND OPEN IT IN ANOTHER TAB AND THEN WHOLE LINK LIKE
you will get something linke this in output window of your repel
[jsonserver.vinayak04.repl.co](https://jsonserver.vinayak04.repl.co/)

just make it a full link like this
https://jsonserver.vinayak04.repl.co/

Comment: thanks alot , but i have one concern ,, after i uploaded my json file can i upload my Reactjs project on gh-pages or vercel to use it live ?

Comment: @HishamMedhat yes afcource you can it will work properly and plz accept the answer and upvote it.   and if you need any help just comment